# Function description vs possible implementation on C++ reference

Tags: c++, standards, requirements

In both the reference pages of [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) and [`std::upper_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) from [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) I read

> [...] uses `operator<` to compare the elements, [...]

This is very useful to me, because with this information I know that, even if the latter function

> Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range `[first, last)` that is *greater* than `value`

it still uses the `operator<` to do so, and not the `operator>`, so the former has to be defined for the class/type of the objects stored in the container. The **Possible implementation** section, with the line `if (!(value < *it)) {`, just confirms this.

However, for instance, the reference page for [`std::remove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove), for which I read that

> Removes all elements that are *equal to* `value`

does not mention any `oparator` at all, so in principle I would not know which one/ones is/are assumed to be defined in the class of the objects stored in the container. The **Possible implementation** uses `operator==` (see the line `if (!(*i == value))`).

Hence my question: is it intentional that the documentation pages of some functions don't specify the "requirements" that the classes on which the function is called must satisfy?

Comment: I believe word "equal" in the definition refers the equality check operator "==". I don't think there can be any confusion on this matter. operator `<` in `map` and `set` was specified because it could've used any of 3 other possibilities, <=, >=,>. I  Note that `std::remove` doesn't work with 'std::set` or `std::map`,

Comment: Remember that `cppreference` is just a website (a *very good one*) mantained by a member of the C++ community. It is *not* authoritative and is not directly related to the work of the standards committee. So it may be incomplete in parts (you can help improve it though, it's a wiki). For *authoritative information*, look up the actual standard document.

Comment: @ALX23z, if I can do something with `==`, then I can do the same thing with `!=` prepending a `!` to the logical expression (e.g. `a == b` is the same as `!(a == b)`). I could also think that checking `==` could be more expensive than checking `!=` and that so it'd be smarter to use the latter.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis  "if I can do something with ==, then I can do the same thing with != prepending a ! to the logical expression (e.g. a == b is the same as !(a == b))." - *Not necessarily true*. C++ supports operator overloading, so a nefarious overload may, for some types, cause "foo == bar" to be *different* from "!(foo != bar)" ..

Comment: Yes, @JesperJuhl, just like `foo < bar` could do something different than `!(foo >= bar)`. My comment is to say that the "prose" description of what the function does could be misleading, as in the case of `std::upper_bound`; therefore, an explicit phrase such as _the operator/function/whatever JohnDoe is used to accomplish the comparison/opration/whatever_ is useful.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Then help us all by editing the description. There's a reason why that site is a wiki after all. Cppreference relies on user contributions to keep it up to date and high quality - do your bit 

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis this is just for clarity. `<` operator can be referred with word "less" in the same manner without any ambiguity, only that writing this way is slightly odd and some less experienced people may still confuse "less" with other operayors written in this way.

Comment: @ALX23z `std::less` and `operator<` are *different things*. Even if they *usually* do the same thing, that does *not* mean that they *always* do.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, I've just edited the wiki.

Comment: @ALX23z Formal definitions are *important* in programming. Especially when the behaviour of your program may differ significantly, depending on you having written `std::less` or `<`. They are *two different things* in C++, for crying out loud. They *mostly* do the same, but not *always* and knowing that is *important* sometimes.

Comment: @JesperJuhl there are great many ways to break one's code. Like making "move" and "copy" constructor behave weirdly. It is an easy way to make great many std and other libraries unable to operate properly with your class. The same is with `std::less` vs `<`. If they do different things then there is something fundamentally wrong with your code. If this doesn't break std code then they can surely break any other libraries. If anything you should argue that standard ought to add a guideline that these two must do the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While cppreference is generally quite good, it is a community-maintained project; not official documentation.  It also sometimes uses slightly ambiguous wording to make the text more understandable.

For the official requirements, we must turn to the standard.  There, all of these requirements are explicitly spelled out:

From [[lower.bound]](http://eel.is/c++draft/lower.bound)

> Let `comp` be `less{}` and `proj` be `identity{}` for overloads with no parameters by those names.
>   ...
>   *Returns*: The furthermost iterator `i` in the range `[first, last]` such that for every iterator `j` in the range `[first, i)`, `bool(invoke(comp, invoke(proj, *j), value))` is `true`.

From [[upper.bound]](http://eel.is/c++draft/upper.bound)

> Let `comp` be `less{}` and `proj` be `identity{}` for overloads with no parameters by those names.
>   ...
>   *Returns*: The furthermost iterator `i` in the range `[first, last]` such that for every iterator `j` in the range `[first, i)`, `!bool(invoke(comp, invoke(proj, *j), value))` is `true`.

From [[alg.remove]](http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.remove)

> Let *E* be
>   -- `bool(*i == value)` for `remove`,
>   ...
>   *Effects*: Eliminates all the elements referred to by iterator `i` in the range `[first, last)` for which *E* holds.

There is no ambiguity in these descriptions.  `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` use `std::less` to do their comparisons by default, and `std::remove` uses `operator==`.

Comment: Might want to add - since the specification of `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` refer to it - something about the specification of `std::less`, and how it uses the `<` operator.